# Картинка-ссылка

Tags: javascript, html

Доброго времени суток.

Подскажите, как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на рисунок был переход по ссылке. Конечно, можно сделать стандартно

```
<a href=primer.html><img src=im/primer.gif></a>
```

но у меня картинка  уже прописывается в css

```
#uzh:hover{ background:url(images/uzh.jpg) no-repeat -4px 1px;}
```

И сам код собственно

```
<div id="uzh">
</div>
```

Слышал, что можно через OnClick или что-то в этом роде, подскажите, плиз. Я только учусь, сильно не серчайте))

Comment: Все верно, через onclick, гуглите этот подход, саморазвивайтесь! Так интереснее!

Comment: Тащем-то идея со скриптом - не оч. Надо просто сделать ссылку блоком, а остальное поведение унаследуется.

Comment: Можно еще через addEventListener() обработать клик на элементе. Это чтобы не засорять html-код.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<style>
  #uzh { display:block; } /* ширину и высоту при необходимости */
  #uzh:hover{ background:url(images/uzh.jpg) no-repeat -4px 1px; }
</style>

<a href="#" id="uzh"></a>
```